# pass variable from html to ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new in Ruby on Rails and I want to pass variable from `index.html.erb` to `search.html.erb` file and use the variable in ruby code.
In other words, I have text and submit button in `index.html.erb`. If I type in text and press the button it will pass what in the text to `search.html.erb` and use that text in ruby code

index.html.erb

```
<h1>Twitter</h1>
<html>
 <form>
   <input type = 'search' name = 'search' /></br>
   <a href=/home/search><button type="button">Search</button></a>
 </form> 
</html>
```

search.html.erb

```
<h1>Twitter</h1>
<html>
  <%=
    require 'twitter'
    client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
      config.consumer_key        = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      config.consumer_secret     = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      config.access_token        = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      config.access_token_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  end %>
  <ul>
    <%=client.search("**I want variable here**", result_type: "recent").take(5).collect do |tweet| %>
      <li><%=  "#{tweet.user.screen_name}: #{tweet.text}" %> </li>   
    <% end %>
   </ul>
</html>
```

Thank you

Comment: Try not to do that inside your view. You should keep stuff like that in your controller, pass it through as `@client`.

Comment: It seems that you're _really_ new and don't have the foggiest idea how rails app works, how it should be organized, how data flows, etc. While I believe in "learning by doing", this is not going to work well here. You'll have much easier time if you complete the rails tutorial first. Or a good rails book (Agile Web Development with Rails, for example). If you don't, you're _bound_ to struggle every part of the way. Structured knowledge is not to be underestimated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to have your ERB structured properly,

```
<% form_tag("/home/search", method: "get") do %>
    <%=text_field_tag(:search)%>
    <%=submit_tag("Search")%>
<%end%>
```

You can send the local variable in the controller that renders the search.html.erb, something like this,

```
get '/hello/search' do
    search_text = params[:search]
    render :search, :locals => {:your_variable => search_text}
end
```

now you can use this variable in views/search.html.erb ,

```
<%=client.search(your_variable, result_type: "recent").take(5).collect do |tweet| %>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use form to pass the data.

```
<%form_for 'url_for_search_page_here' do %>
    <%=text_field_tag :search%>
    <%=submit_tag, "Search"%>
<%end%>
```

by using the form tag you got the `params[:serach]` with value in your search action or where you to submit you form.

Answer (score 1):

You have to mention action parameter in your form which goes to that action with the user entered parameters. Inside that action you can get the parameters and use in your html pages.

First of all I suggest to use ruby form helper methods instead of plain html because you can easily build your forms (You can use ruby gems like "simple_form")

```
<%= form_for "<search_url_here>" do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :search %>
  <%= f.text_field :search %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

In your search method

```
def search
  @search_term = params[:search]
end
```

In your search.html.erb page you can access as @search_term

Comment: when I type and then press search to go to search.html.erb, I get this errer"No route matches [POST] "/home/index" in route.rb I have 
get 'home/index', to: 'home#index'
get 'home/search', to: 'home#search'

Comment: In general form will take default method as "post". the request is entitled as post, when user input is being posted to the server with user entered parameters. So in your routes.rb file you have to mention:
 post   'login'   => 'sessions#create'

Comment: @Mohammed here in your routes.rb you need to write: `post 'search' => 'home#search'`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it will be much better if you add the twitter configuration in an initializer file and make it accessible globally. As much as possible, try to avoid having too much logic on your view.

e.g.

```
# config/initializers/twitter.rb
$twitter_client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
             config.consumer_key = ENV['CONSUMER_KEY']
             config.consumer_secret = ENV['CONSUMER_SECRET']
             config.access_token = ENV['YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN']
             config.access_token_secret = ENV['YOUR_ACCESS_SECRET']
           end
```

while the search form should look like this as Pardeep Saini advised

```
#app/views/index.html.erb

<%= form_tag 'your_path_for_search' do %>
  <%=text_field_tag :search%>
  <%=submit_tag, "Search"%>
<% end %>
```

then on your search controller and view

```
#app/controllers/search_controller.rb

def search
  @result = $twitter_client.search(params[:search], result_type: "recent").take(5)
end

#app/views/search.html.erb
<ul>
  <%= @result.each do |tweet| %>
    <li><%=  "#{tweet.user.screen_name}: #{tweet.text}" %> </li>   
  <% end %>
</ul>
```